# How to webscrape from a selected tab with an embedded table on a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.onthesnow.com/alberta/lake-louise/historical-snowfall however the default script only shows the monthly totals and not the annual totals. There is a tab you have to select 'Annual' on the webpage to show the annual totals. [website source code showing the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8k4S.png) I can successfully scrape the monthly totals but I am unsuccessful in returning the annual totals. [Annual totals table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KGvE.png)

```
def historic_snowfall():
    #Resort naming convetion on OpenSnow.com
    # Revelstoke, BC: british-columbia, revelstoke-mountain
    # Whistler, BC: british-columbia, whistler-blackcomb
    # Lake Louise, AB: alberta, lake-louise
    # Big Sky, MT: montana, big-sky-resort
    # Snowbird, UT: utah, snowbird
    # Palisades: califronia, squaw-valley-usa
    # Steamboat, CO: colorado, steamboat
    # Copper Mountain, CO: colorado, copper-mountain
    # Aspen, CO: colorado, aspen-snowmass
    # Jackson Hole, WY: wyoming, jackson-hole
    # Taos, NM: taos-ski-valley
    
    resort_table = ['alberta/lake-louise',
                    'montana/big-sky-resort',
                    'utah/snowbird',
                    'california/squaw-valley-usa',
                    'colorado/steamboat',
                    'colorado/copper-mountain',
                    'colorado/aspen-snowmass',
                    'wyoming/jackson-hole',
                    'new-mexico/taos-ski-valley'
                    ]

    resort = (resort_table[1])
    
    hsnow_url = 'https://www.onthesnow.com/' + resort + '/historical-snowfall'
    page = requests.get(hsnow_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
 
    data = []
    table = soup.find('table')                      # Find table
    table_body = table.find('tbody')                # Find body of table

    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')                #find rows within table
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')                   # within rows pull column data
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
        
    return data     #returns monthly averages not yearly results
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Json data embedded inside the HTML page to get the annual info:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.onthesnow.com/alberta/lake-louise/historical-snowfall"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["props"]["pageProps"]["snowfallInfoAnnual"])
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| date | totalSnow | snowDays | baseDepth | summitDepth | maxBaseDepth | biggestSnowfall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | 467 | 80 | 25.2892 | 128.724 | 118 | 28 |
| 2013-01-01 | 756 | 89 | 111.013 | 123.061 | 207 | 40 |
| 2014-01-01 | 465 | 64 | 77.3352 | 105.181 | 158 | 34 |
| 2015-01-01 | 339 | 60 | 75.5234 | 95.4746 | 125 | 54 |
| 2016-01-01 | 544 | 95 | 99.4935 | 147.88 | 177 | 30 |
| 2017-01-01 | 737 | 89 | 114.79 | 153.75 | 192 | 41 |
| 2018-01-01 | 505 | 81 | 98.2466 | 124.705 | 158 | 71 |
| 2019-01-01 | 537 | 73 | 76.7257 | 84.805 | 188 | 36 |
| 2020-01-01 | 445 | 76 | 88.5694 | 110.969 | 183 | 38 |
| 2021-01-01 | 669 | 96 | 118.13 | 168.105 | 178 | 54 |
| 2022-01-01 | 111 | 14 | 39.9333 | 47.7667 | 52 | 24 |
| Average | 507 | 75 | 85 | 118 | 158 | 41 |

Answer (score 1):

I would leave this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation, but you can get the data directly:

Monthly:
https://api.onthesnow.com/api/v2/resort/368/snowfall/monthly

Annual:
https://api.onthesnow.com/api/v2/resort/368/snowfall/annual

Example data returned:

{"snowfallItems":[{"date":"2012-01-01","totalSnow":467,"snowDays":80,"baseDepth":25.2892,"summitDepth":128.72395779996586,"maxBaseDepth":118,"biggestSnowfall":28}]}

Note: Each measurement is in centimetres rather than inches so you might have to convert it.

Edit: The other (BETTER) answer basically does this and makes things beautiful in a table too

Answer (score 1):

If you can use find_all() function instead of find() while searching tables, you can get the annual table as well. So the code should be like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

def historic_snowfall():
    #Resort naming convetion on OpenSnow.com
    # Revelstoke, BC: british-columbia, revelstoke-mountain
    # Whistler, BC: british-columbia, whistler-blackcomb
    # Lake Louise, AB: alberta, lake-louise
    # Big Sky, MT: montana, big-sky-resort
    # Snowbird, UT: utah, snowbird
    # Palisades: califronia, squaw-valley-usa
    # Steamboat, CO: colorado, steamboat
    # Copper Mountain, CO: colorado, copper-mountain
    # Aspen, CO: colorado, aspen-snowmass
    # Jackson Hole, WY: wyoming, jackson-hole
    # Taos, NM: taos-ski-valley
    
    resort_table = ['alberta/lake-louise',
                    'montana/big-sky-resort',
                    'utah/snowbird',
                    'california/squaw-valley-usa',
                    'colorado/steamboat',
                    'colorado/copper-mountain',
                    'colorado/aspen-snowmass',
                    'wyoming/jackson-hole',
                    'new-mexico/taos-ski-valley'
                    ]

    resort = (resort_table[1])
    
    hsnow_url = 'https://www.onthesnow.com/' + resort + '/historical-snowfall'
    page = requests.get(hsnow_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    

    data = []
    data2 = []
    table = soup.find_all('table')                      # Find table

    table_body_1 = table[0].find('tbody')                # Find body of table
    rows_table_1 = table_body_1.find_all('tr')                #find rows within table
    for row in rows_table_1:
        cols = row.find_all('td')                   # within rows pull column data
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values

    table_body_2 = table[1].find('tbody')                # Find body of table
    rows_table_2 = table_body_2.find_all('tr')                #find rows within table
    for row in rows_table_2:
        cols = row.find_all('td')                   # within rows pull column data
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data2.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
        
    return data,data2     #returns monthly averages not yearly results


print(historic_snowfall())
```